# In SPARK, How to define common UDF/codebase, which will be shared by all scala script

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have multiple scala scripts in SPARK and each script required `uprUDF`

Eg. Test1.scala

```
val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val uprUDF = udf((lname: String
                  ) => {
  lname.toUpperCase
})
dataset.withColumn("upper", uprUDF('text)).show
```

Here `uprUDF` is a user defined function and want to put `uprUDF` in some common code-base/script where all other scala script able to access `uprUDF`.

Like as Hive, we created udf in java (repository of commonly use UDFs) and register in Hive to use it.

My Question

1. How can we achieve this?
   a. How we create/maintain common code-base and
   b. How we can access common code in Test1.scala

Comment: I think the scope of UDFs is limited to that particular SparkSession in which they are registered.

Comment: @philantrovert, You are right. Like as hive we defined UDF in one common file(java) and registered it to use. Can we implement same thing in Spark?

Comment: I think you can define one `object SparkUDFs`. Put all your scala functions in that. Then whenever you want to use those, you can `import package.SparkUDFs` and in your main program `val myUDF = udf(SparkUDFs.myUDF)`

Comment: Really good post that most do not know about

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of standalone Spark scripts, and can be eliminated by building the required scala classes in a jar which then gets deployed and run on a cluster. In the scala classes the common UDF utility functions can be aggregated inside one class which can be imported when needed into the main spark application runnable classes.
A standard way to build spark jar would be to use the maven build tool.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html